# Naming conventions for naming files that would start with a dot usually

Tags: finder

How should i name music artists beginning with a dot (such as .38 special https://musicbrainz.org/artist/0330a83d-f61e-4989-adb3-afce3943c3ba ) so that they are not hidden from Finder because of the dot.

I realize that just removing the dot does the trick, but I'm looking to see if there is a for sensible naming convention for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in iTunes you do not need to worry as iTunes will automatically use an underscore in place of certain characters. For example, the artist folder for `.38 Special` will be named `_38 Special` and the folder for `“Weird Al” Yankovic` or `"Weird Al" Yankovic` *(curly or straight quotes)* will be named `_Weird Al_ Yankovic`

Comment: Ah thanks its not directly iTunes but it is Music so seems like a sensible to follow that naming convention

Answer (score 1):

You could try some Unicode 'dot equivalent' like
· [Unicode U+0087 UTF-8 C2 B7] or
․ [Unicode U+2024 UTF-8 E2 80 A4] or
⠠ [U+2820 UTF-8 E2 A0 A0]

Try the Character Viewer in System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard. Type 'dot' & see what may work

Comment: Thanks that a good idea, but because its Music related Im going to go with the iTunes naming conventions answer.